# Configure navigation property for one to many in EF Core 3 not using primary keys?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using **EF Core 3.0** I am trying to configure a **one-to-many** navigation between the following two classes.

```
public class Organization
{
    public decimal Id{get;set;}
    public int ClientId{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int? ClientId{get;set;}
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

I need to have the navigation use the `ClientId` fields rather than any the Primary Keys.

I have tried both annotations and Fluent

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOne<Organization>(o => o.Organization)
            .WithMany(c => c.Contacts)
            .HasForeignKey("ClientId");
```

But for some reason it keeps going back to connection the `ClientId` to the `Id` of the Organization.

How can this be configured?

**Yes the Id field in the legacy db is a decimal but I can not change that.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the database already has a Foreign Key declared from Contact.ClientId to Organization.ClientId, try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
      .HasOne<Organization>(o => o.Organization)
      .WithMany(c => c.Contacts)
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.ClientId)
      .HasPrincipalKey(org => org.ClientId);
```

For more details: [Alternate Keys in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#alternate-keys)

Comment: This implies that `Organization.ClientId` is unique though.

Comment: The target of an Foreign Key must have a unique index or unique constraint in the DBMS.

Comment: That's obvious. What I meant was that the principal field doesn't look like that, and bad things will happen if you fool the EF Core that the field is unique while it isn't (apparently OP is not using migrations and is mapping to existing database, so the unique constraint that EF Core creates when the database is maintained with migrations might not even exist). IMHO this is important, otherwise the whole question and answer make no sense since all that is contained in the EF Core documentation.

Comment: Absolutely.  I was _assuming_ that since this is an existing, legacy database it already has a Foreign Key.